# Reporting & send email (total: 20 job) from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I must send email with (total reporting 20 job) from Jenkins,
But how to make Report total?

I mean: Send email with Totaly reporting of 20 job 
(Note: Send report attachment **Metric build Result**)

[image]

Comment: What does a "report total" mean to you? Is it referring to the last results of the 20 build job?

Comment: I mean total results of 20 job . I need to send email with that result ( I try to do Metric Build Plugin - It show result 20 job - But i dont know how to send email automatic) . Please to help me